# how to automate or verify smart home devices

Tags: python, automation, appium, robotframework

**Automation of Smart Home devices**

To verify smart home devices like end-to-end (from mobile App to smart home devices).
what are the automation framework you suggests.

1. Mobile App - developed Appium with python and Robot
2. Product - REST
3. API calls.  Smart Devices - Verification of lights ON/OFF, color
   change, etc

Can you please suggest or add any better methods to verify end-to-end.
EG: Image comparison, any other method.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on two things:

1- How the devices are calling each other. And whats is the main controller.

2- Whats you purpose of testing? Testing the devices themselves or testing the functionality of the control panel and softwares?

**About CP and softwares:**

If the system using API > Of course api-testing is required

If there are a panel and you can access it with browser> Using selenium for desktop and chromedriver for mobile browser

If there are a mobile app, using Appium

etc.

**For the system itself**, it is completely another field and responsibility of the electronic and robot engineers. And depends on hardwares. But the general way is I/O checking. Means that engineers check the input signal with device actions and vice-versa.
Hope this helps.